# Functionality Like left inner join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, inner-join

In our transaction we have 2 steps
For that we have TxnStepDetails table.

```
TxnId   stepId  status  retryCount
100     step1   0       1
100     step2   0       1
101     step1   0       1
```

My requirement is that I want all the transactions where I have step2 corresponding to step1.
I am using following query.

```
select a.txnid txnid,
       a.stepid as stepida,
       a.status as statusa,
       b.stepid as stepidb,
       b.status as statusb
  from txnstepdetails a left join txnstepdetails b on a.txnid = b.txnid
 where     a.retrycount > 0
       and a.stepid = 'step1'
       and b.stepid = 'step2';
```

Output:

```
TxnId   stepIdA     statusA     stepIdB     statusB
100     step1       0           step2       0
```

But my expected output is:

```
TxnId   stepIdA     statusA     stepIdB     statusB
100     step1       0           step2       0
101     step1       0           null        null
```

I have searched for the result of **LEFT INNER JOIN** but there is no such thing.
What changes do I make in my query so that I get desired result.

Comment: Move the b.stepId condition from WHERE to ON to get left join result.

Comment: How about googling "left join" before you use it in a program? PS What does "where I have step2 corresponding to step1" mean? You need to use more words & actually clearly say what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `where` condition on the outer joined table turns the outer join into an inner join. You need to move that condition into the `JOIN`

```
select a.TxnId TxnId,
       a.stepId as stepIdA,
       a.status as statusA,  
       b.stepI as stepIdB, 
       b.status as statusB 
from TxnStepDetails a 
  LEFT JOIN TxnStepDetails b  
         on a.TxnId = b.TxnId   
        and b.stepId='step2'
where and a.retryCount>0 
  and a.stepId='step1';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TxnId,
       regexp_substr(stepId, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as stepIdA,
       regexp_substr(status, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as statusA, 
       regexp_substr(stepId, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as stepIdB,
       regexp_substr(status, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as statusB
From
(
SELECT 
    TxnId ,
    LISTAGG(stepId, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TxnId) AS stepId,
    LISTAGG(status, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TxnId) AS status
FROM table1
GROUP BY TxnId
)
```

Output

```
TXNID   STEPIDA STATUSA STEPIDB STATUSB
100     step1   0       step2   0
101     step1   0       (null)  (null)
```

Demo Link

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9dd7a/17

Answer (score 0):

Please check LAG(Analytic Function) in oracle.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm

This will return you a corresponding value as last step

```
SELECT txnid, stepid, status, LAG(stepid, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY txnid ORDER BY ?) AS "stepiIdB", LAG(status, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY txnid ORDER BY ?) AS "statusB"
```

FROM txnstepdetails;

This will give you a resultset, which list you all steps with the corresponding last stepid an status. You need to define an order to give oracle a hint how the resultset must be order e.g. creation date. Otherwise for the dbms it is unclear if step1 was timewise before step2 or in the other order. Oracle does not promise the a select returns date in the same order as they were inserted. If you want an order by time, you have to add a timestamp column to order on it.